# How to open upsell products in popup?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using fancybox for pop and I want to open up upsell products link in that popup. But I am not sure where or how to get the link for all the upsell products page to open up in popup window?

Answer (score 0):

Just placed in this block and rest was fancybox responsible to make it popup. Hope it help someone:

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="data">
          <?php if ($this->getChildHtml('upsell_products2')): ?>
               <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products2'); ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
     </div>
</div>
```